# Equation to represent mountain-with-hollow-like surface

Tags: matlab, math, plot, distribution

I want to use function where x and y are coordinates forming circle, z(x, y) grows from 0 at the edge to max at the R/2 and back to 0 at the center without sharp changes. I stucked with

```
t = -pi:pi/180:pi;
R = 5;
x = R*cos(t);
y = R*sin(t);

for i = 1:361
  for j = 1:361
     z(i,j) = exp( sqrt((x(i)).^2 + (y(j)).^2));
  end
end
[u, v] = meshgrid(x, y);
mesh(u, v, z), grid on;
```

How should I realize z to add this drop to the middle? Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe subtract two 2D gaussians with a different standard deviation?

```
% the area
x = linspace(-5,5,1E2);
y = linspace(-5,5,1E2);

sig1=1;
sig2=2;

%2D gaussian
efac = 1/(2*sig1);
X   = exp(-efac*x.^2);
Y   = exp(-efac*y.^2)';
z1    = Y*X;
z1=z1./max(z1(:));

%2D gaussian
efac = 1/(2*sig2);
X   = exp(-efac*x.^2);
Y   = exp(-efac*y.^2)';
z2    = Y*X;
z2=z2./max(z2(:));

[u, v] = meshgrid(x, y);
mesh(u, v, z2-z1), grid on;
```

[image: vulcano]

An alternative that has zero outside of R and is more along the lines of your own code:

```
x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,1E2);
y = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,1E2);
[u, v] = meshgrid(x, y);
r = sqrt(u.^2+v.^2);
z = sin(r);
z(r>pi)=0;

mesh(u, v, z), grid on;
```

[image: another vulcano]

Or to make it a little less sharp at the base:

```
z = sin(r).^2;
```

[image]

Comment: Won't be a zero at the edge as OP wanted

Comment: True. Is the new version more to your liking?